# Efficient bit field extraction from bytes array being interpreted as a bitstream, possibly using Intel's BMI Set 1

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, bit-manipulation, intel

In order to extract bit fields from a bytes array being interpreted as a bitstream, I am aiming to device an *efficient* bit field extraction function, optimized for Intel's modern CPUs (ideally making use of the new [BEXTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI1_.28Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_1.29) instruction) and MS Visual Studio 2017 (I'm developing in VB.NET).

```
Inputs: Bitstream left to right (MSB first)
        Pos=0...7, Len=1...8
Output: bitfield at Pos in length Len (LSB right-aligned)
```

As an example for `Pos=0...7` and `Len=3` (masking omitted):

```
Byte0    Byte1    Shifts       
01234567 01234567 
xxx               >> 5
 xxx              >> 4
  xxx             >> 3
   xxx            >> 2
    xxx           >> 1
     xxx          n/a
      xx x        << 1 | >> 7
       x xx       << 2 | >> 6
```

From the example, a possibly naive implementation in pseudo-code would be:

```
Extract(Pos, Len, ByteAddr):=
    if 8-Pos-Len > 0
        Res:=[ByteAddr+0] >> 8-Pos-Len
        Res:=Res & (2^Len-1)
    elseif 8-Pos-Len < 0
        Res:=[ByteAddr+0] << Pos+Len-8
        Res:=Res & (2^Len-1)
        Res:=Res | ([ByteAddr+1] >> 16-Pos-Len))
    else
        Res:=[ByteAddr+0] & (2^Len-1)
    fi
```

Testing this on "paper" (well, `notepad.exe` these days) for `Len=4` and `Pos=0...7` shows, that the algorithm is likely to work:

```
Byte0    Byte1    B0>>      B0<<      &(2^Len-1) B1>>       B0|B1
                  8-Pos-Len Pos+Len-8            16-Pos-Len 
01234567 01234567 01234567  01234567  01234567   01234567   01234567
xxxx....        | 0000xxxx         |  0000xxxx          |          |
.xxxx...        | 000.xxxx         |  0000xxxx          |          |
..xxxx..        | 00..xxxx         |  0000xxxx          |          |
...xxxx.        | 0...xxxx         |  0000xxxx          |          |
....xxxx        |                  |  0000xxxx          |          |
.....xxx y.......           ....xxx0  0000xxx0   0000000y   0000xxxy
......xx yy......           ....xx00  0000xx00   000000yy   0000xxyy
.......x yyy.....           ....x000  0000x000   00000yyy   0000xyyy
```

**Questions:**

(1) For efficiency reasons, should I use a lookup table instead of `2^Len-1`, or can I rely on the compiler to reliably optimize powers of 2? (Of course, I could also use `(1<<Len)-1`. Does the compiler do this?)

(2) In VB.NET, how would I proceed to instruct the compiler to pretty please make use of the new `BEXTR` instruction?

(3) Should I do this completely different, i.e. package everything in lookup tables? (After all, it's just 8 x 8 possibilities. However, it would not truly be expandable.)

Comment: *"In VB.NET, how would I proceed to instruct the compiler to pretty please make use of the new BEXTR instruction?"* You cannot. You have one option, and one option only: write the function in another language (C or assembler would be reasonable choices), compile it into a DLL, and then p/invoke that exported function from the DLL in your VB.NET app. Does that change whether you are willing to pursue this?

Comment: "*efficient* ... optimized for Intel's modern CPUs  ... I'm developing in VB.NET" - some of these words do not belong together.

Comment: @CodyGray, a pity that there's no inline assembler in .NET, but I guess I understand that it would be quite awkward for the CLR to handle registers. Of course, I do not really like the certainty in your comment, as it seems to imply, that explicitely coding `(src >> start) & ((1 << len)-1)` will not influence the compiler in any way to use `BEXTR` rather than doing the two shifts, the subtraction and the And. But thanks anyway!

Comment: There cannot *possibly* be an inline assembler. The CLR is platform-independent, whereas assembly language is obviously platform-specific. Yes, in theory, writing the code a certain way could influence the JIT compiler to emit certain instructions, but on the current implementation, it does not; hence the certainty. These newer instructions are not used by the current JIT compilers.

Comment: 1) the optimizer is likely to convert 2^n into a shift, however if your goal is performance you cannot rely on the optimizer behaviour. (1<<Len)-1 is preferable over a lookup table, since the latter requires much more operations over slower components (memory, or CPU cache in the best case).